# Illustrator: How to make a precise circular arc with ratio and length

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, drawing

I'm trying to make a label for a conical shape. Just imagine a starbucks cup with a promotional adhesive all around. To do so, I need to make the technical drawing of this cup.

The top diameter is 8cm, bottom diameter is 5,1cm and height is 10,5cm. 
I know that my top arc length is 25,136cm and the bottom 16,024cm.

And I also know the diameter of the two circles for construction purposes, which are 58,1501cm and 37,07cm.

In the end, I just need a way to make a precise cut on the two circles to get the legnth I need.

I know that I should be doing this on CAD, but isn't there any way to do this in illustrator?

[image: this is the shape desired, but it isn't technical]

[image: both arches that I know the length but have to cut precisely]

THANKS!

Answer (score 7):

Draw your second image, without the arrows.

Select all

Click the *Divide* button on the **Pathfinder Panel**.

Delete what you don't need

[image]